# Получить градиент с фото

Tags: css, css3, градиент, linear-gradient

Есть фотка с градиентом, мне необходимо получить CSS градиент. Можете помочь с этим? Есть ли инструменты для этого? (В макете вставлена именно фотка)

Методом тыка я смог получить градиент, но он не особо похож. (В сниппете он почему-то не правильно отображается)

```css
body
{
  background: linear-gradient(-35deg, #7889B0  0%, #7FA9D0 75%, #CACFCC 100%);
}
```

Необходимый градиент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чём проблема изображение использовать?

Comment: Не любитель вставлять изображение везде, если можно обойтись css - я выберу его.

Comment: Но ведь поддержка изображений в более большом кол-ве браузеров есть, разве изображение не лучше будет тогда?

Comment: Данный проект все равно на реакте, в котором есть авто префиксер и все такое, разве у linear-gradient настолько плохая поддержка?

Comment: Сами сравните поддержку [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient#browser_compatibility), с [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/html/element/img#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Ну вполне себе хорошая поддержка.

Comment: Я посмотрел что можно сделать через CSS, получилось только что-то такое: `background: conic-gradient(rgb(231, 222, 200) 0%, rgb(118, 154, 196) 10%, rgb(106, 134, 182) 71%, rgb(231, 222, 200) 80%);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background gradient отображается как-то корявенько.. Можно что-то подобное еще с background-img попробовать сделать там вроде нет таких коллизий..

```css
.a {
  width: 500px;
  height: 280px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(10% 15%, #E7DECA, #77baca 47%, #607bb1 90%);
  filter: blur(0.5px);
}

.a::before {
  content: '';
  width: 500px;
  height: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(98% 75%, transparent, #77baca 47%, transparent 95%);
  filter: blur(3px);
}

.a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 500px;
  height: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(-60% 100%, #607bb1 1%, transparent 50%, transparent 66%);
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div class='a'></div>
```

Comment: Это шикарно) Спасибо!

Comment: @OliverPatterson На здоровье! :)

Comment: @OliverPatterson Ночью делал.. overflow оставил не уследил.. Сразу не сообразил заблюрить.. Так вроде с коллизией получается бороться, результат на мой взгляд лучше.. Единственное по поддержке filter как приемлемо, или нет..